# Is there an alternative way to express "has them <verb>" other than "makes them <verb>"?

Tags: verbs

For example, in the following sentence, can I replace *have them* with *makes them*, or is there another verb that more correctly I could use instead of *has*?

> Since the manufacturers are so deeply involved, in some cases Wal-Mart even **has them handle** their own distribution, saving the retailer big bucks and increasing profit margins on cheaper goods.

Another example could be the following one.

> The doctor sends my father and Uncle Johnnie out for all the ice they can get. Then he **has them dump** the ice in the bathtub, add cold water almost to the top, whereupon my aunt is wrestled into the tub and submerged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several constructions of the form

- *have `NP VP`* (*to* not allowed)

One of them is a causative construction; as noted, there are other causatives as well. A causative always entails that an event happened or a state changed; but there are different ways to cause this, and different ways to talk about it.

- *make `NP VP`* (*to* not allowed)
  *I made him examine me* means I forced him to do it.
- *get `NP` to `VP`* (*to* required)
  *I got him to examine me* means I had to persuade him to do it.
- *caused `NP` to `VP`* (*to* required)
  *I caused him to examine me* means only that he did it and I was responsible. It's very formal.

The causative *have `NP VP`* construction is quite common with a past participle clause

- *I had my tires replaced yesterday, while my car was in the shop.*
  (basically a passive with indefinite subject, from *I had them replace my tires*)

There's another very different *have `NP VP`* construction - the subject is not the agent but the patient.

- *I had my tires slashed last night, while my car was parked outside.*

This one is always passive and often (though not always) deals with a bad outcome

- *I had my dearest dreams crushed by their betrayal.*
- *I had my wildest dreams fulfilled by their assistance.*

Answer (score 6):

They are both correct, but "has them" is a much gentler way of stating things.  "Makes them" is harsh and commanding.  If you are writing a positive or informative article about WalMart, "has them" would be good.  If you are upset about how WalMart treats its manufacturers, use "makes them".

Answer (score 3):

It is probably somewhere between "instructs them to" and "makes them" depending on the context. "makes them" is rather strong language and probably should be reserved for situations where there is some force behind the action, for example a contract with Wal-Mart.

"has them" is fine, but is vague related to the intended meaning.

Answer (score 0):

A minuscule grab-bag of alternate verbs for various shades of causation: you can command, demand, pay, wheedle, beg, force, cause, insist, browbeat, blackmail, order, bribe, threaten, intimidate, and so forth. Some of these are direct replacements, but most need additional bits of grammar -- in place of "has them sing" you'd have to say something like "bribes them to sing" or "threatens them into singing." Although I'll admit usually the problem is to get singers to *stop* singing.

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thank you for your answer. Please take a few minutes to review our [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. Remember: explaining _why_ is as important as telling _what_ for new learners of English. We hope you'll contribute more!